# Lot of time spent with following waits 'SQL*Net message from client' and 'wait for unread message on broadcast channel'

Tags: oracle, performance, wait, datapump, impdp

My application that wraps around Oracle Data pump's executables IMPDP and EXPDP takes random amounts of time for the same work. On further investigation, I see it waiting for again random amounts of time with the event 'wait for unread message on broadcast channel'. This makes the application take anytime b/w 10 minutes to over an hour for the same work.

I fail to understand if this has something to do with the way my application uses these executables, or it has got something to do with Load on my server or something totally alien to me.

Comment: Network activity ? Maybe if you said whether you get these on the imp or exp side (or any other details about what is going on) you may get some more answers.

Comment: This is the case for both export side and import side and both sometimes. I will look into network activity in a little greater detail to see if there is something wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of [processes and sessions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10701/dp_overview.htm#i1010261) involved in a data pump operation.
I suspect you are looking at the master processes, not at the worker processes. So all that event is saying is that the Master process spends more time waiting for the worker process when the job takes longer. Which is fairly useless information.

You need to monitor the worker processes and see why they are taking longer.

Answer (score 0):

Those wait events are *usually* considered to be "idle" waits - i.e. Oracle has nothing to do, it is waiting for further data/instructions.

Comment: My question exactly, these are idle waits and I still see expdp if invoked directly from my console, showing me these waits (So, it can't be waiting on something?). So was curious if there is something I am missing here. I am more curious about expdp's behavior and not faulting what Oracle is trying to do as such.